# How polymorphism works involving multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions, vtable

I'm studying topics related to multiple inheritance now. I came up with the following code, and couldn't totally figure out the mechanism behind it:

```
struct root
{
    virtual void vfunction(){ /* root version */ }
};

struct mid1:public root
{
    virtual void vfunction(){ /* mid1 version */ }
};

struct mid2:public root
{
    virtual void vfunction(){ /* mid2 version */ }
};

struct inheritMulti:public mid1, public mid2
{
    void ambiguityMethod(){
        vfunction();    // error: ambiguous
    }
    void method1(){
        mid1& t = *this;
        t.vfunction();
    }
    void method2(){
        mid2& t = *this;
        t.vfunction();
    }
};
```

The `ambiguityMethod` is an error, obviously. However, the function calls in both `method1` and `method2` confused me. They are virtual function call as well, and `t` is actually of type `inheritMulti`. So they should call the `inheritMulti` version of `vfunction`, but since `inheritMulti` doesn't have its own version, I don't know what will happen. And it turns out the call in `method1` calls the `mid1` version, while the call in `method2` calls the `mid2` version. Is it something undefined and only happened on my compiler? If not, why does it works like this? How does the vtable handle this kind of situation? Thanks!

---

Thanks for helping in the first place. I have searched about relating topics myself, so yes, I know "diamond problem". But I think my question is different from that. My main concern is whether the behavior of "virtual function call" in `method1` and `method2` well-defined or undefined by the standard. In compiler, it behaved like what I mentioned above, but is the behavior promised by the standard? If it is well-defined, why does it call the `mid1` and 'mid2' version respectively? (The intuitive thought would be calling the `inheritMulti` version since the type of `t` is actually `inheritMulti`) And also, how does most of the compilers handle this situation? It is weird that virtual function call in `method1` and `method2` call different functions. Thanks again!

Comment: what dou you think should happen here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void method1(){
    mid1& t = *this;
    t.vfunction();
}
```

Here you are calling `vfunction` which is not defined in `inheritMulti`hence it will search for the nearest definition of `vfunction`, and that is present in `mid1`. See the hierarchy.

Root->Mid1->inheritMulti

Root->Mid2->inheritMulti

same in the case of

```
`void method2(){
    mid2& t = *this;
    t.vfunction();
}
```

Here also the nearest definition was found in mid2 and hence the output. These calls are not ambiguous because both structures have created there own copy of `vfunction`.

`inheritMulti` will have two Subobjects named `mid1` and `mid2`, and each of these subobjects maintain their own vtable pointer. Though you may think that when you do

```
mid1& t1 = *this;
```

and `mid2& t2 = *this;`

both t1 and t2 are same, but try doing this...

```
bool same = ((void*)t1) == ((void*)t2);  // Result false!
```

Because compiler generates some code behind to adjust the pointer to point the proper object.

Comment: Thanks! But there's one more question left. How does the vtable works if multiple inheritance involved like this one?

Answer (score 1):

The virtual keyword does not play here at all.
when two classes has functions with the same name, and a third class inherits from them both, you need to manually specify on which base class are you refereing when you invoke that function with the scope operator `::`  .

```
 void ambiguityMethod(){
        mid1::vfunction();
    }
```

or

```
 void ambiguityMethod(){
        mid2::vfunction();
    }
```

or

```
 void ambiguityMethod(){
        root::vfunction();
    }
```

with t : (warning: weird syntax ahead!)
`t.mid1::vfunction();`

you can also override this function and call some base class function, thus specifing just once which function are you invoking:

```
void inheritMulti::vfunction() override {
  return mid1::vfunction();
}
```

the compiler will search for the nearest function with the same signature when calling `vfunction`, and will call this function which in its turn - will call `mid1` function

Answer (score 1):

Your code is describing "The diamond problem" well known problem in multiple inheritance (for `vfunction`). For `method1` and `method2` everything is ok, because you are making `mid1` and `mid2` objects from `this` and call `vfunction` from their namespaces.

Comment: Not really a diamond, and not a problem. You can be ambiguities whenever you have MI or even multiple `using namespace` or with language with "import" when you have multiple import.